# Making labels with symbols in PGFPlot optional -- TeX error: Missing \endcsname inserted

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to create a custom plotting command that optionally creates a label. For this I use the `ifthenelse` package -- though there might be better ways, it works for me. The problem occurs when I want to create a label with an additional symbol, e.g. `\prime`, `\star` or `\ast` but not with an asterix `*`.

Here is a MVE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{ifthen}

% define new plotting command
\newcommand{\plotMyGraph}[1]{
    % make input variable
    \ifthenelse{#1>0}{
        \def\xTickLbl{ xlabel={test$^\ast$} }
        }{
        \def\xTickLbl{ xlabel={test$^*$} }
        }
    % create picture
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                    xmin=0,     xmax=1,
                    ymin=-1,    ymax=1,
                    \xTickLbl,
                    ylabel={Test}
                    ]

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture} 
}

% main document
\begin{document}
    This is a test document.

    \plotMyGraph{0} % works smoothly
    \plotMyGraph{1} % this causes an error
\end{document}
```

It throws the error `Missing \endcsname inserted. \plotMyGraph{1}`
It seems to be a TeX error but my knowledge is too limited to guess, why the command `\ast` does not work but the shortcut `*` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are expansion issues. Here is one simple way to make it work.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 

\usepackage{pgfplots}

% define new plotting command
\newcommand{\plotMyGraph}[1]{
    % make input variable
    % create picture
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                    xmin=0,     xmax=1,
                    ymin=-1,    ymax=1,
                    xlabel={\ifnum#1>0 test$^{\ast}$ \else test$^*$ \fi},
                    ylabel={Test}
                    ]

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture} 
}

% main document
\begin{document}
This is a test document.

\plotMyGraph{0} % works smoothly

\plotMyGraph{1} % works smoothly
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is another way.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 

\usepackage{pgfplots}

% define new plotting command
\newcommand{\plotMyGraph}[1]{
    % make input variable
    % create picture
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \ifnum#1>0%added second \ast just to make the results distiguishable
        \pgfplotsset{my x label/.style={xlabel=test$^{\ast\ast}$}} 
        \else
        \pgfplotsset{my x label/.style={xlabel=test$^*$}}
        \fi
        \begin{axis}[
                    xmin=0,     xmax=1,
                    ymin=-1,    ymax=1,
                    my x label,
                    ylabel={Test}
                    ]

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture} 
}

% main document
\begin{document}
This is a test document.

\plotMyGraph{0} % works smoothly

\plotMyGraph{1} % works smoothly
\end{document}
```

What is "best" depends on what you are really going to do with it.

Comment: So the problem is to combine `xlabel=` with *\ifthenelese* or *\if*. thx

Comment: @max It is a bit more complex than that. But one problem of `\ifthenelse` is that it is not expandable, another one that you should not set `pgf` keys like this.

Comment: @Schrödingerscat What would be the correct way, to variably set pgf keys? I'm always happy to learn s.th.=)

Comment: @max You can use `\pgfplotsset`, I added an example. Please note that the first case *is* a proper way to do that. If you look at the source code of `pgfplots`, say, you will find more then enough (expandable) `\ifnum`, `\ifdim` or `\ifcase` statements in the styles.

Comment: @Schrödingerscat this works even better (for my special purpose) and I like the clarity. thx for the lesson today